# selecting last elements based on their grandparent in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have one grandfather div which has three fathers , each father has multiple divs as in the code below:

```
<div id="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
        <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
        <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
        <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

i want to select all child threes (in my real code it is not structured as organized meaning that there may be alot of other divs between the children,parents ,grandparents and different in all three cases and they dont have specific ids nor is it known the number of children it can only work by selecting the last of its parent )

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, that's not valid HTML markup

Comment: Please write the question in the cleaner way so that we could help you

Answer (score 3):

According to your title:

> selecting last elements based on their grandparent

The selector would be:

```
#grandparent > * > :last-child
```

And if by “last elements” you mean the innermost elements, then

```
$('#grandparent div').not(':has(*)')
```

is what you are looking for. But generally, adding a class to the elements and using a class selector is much more efficient.

Comment: Not sure the purpose of making it a community wiki answer, not sure this question deserve it. Maybe i don't understand the meaning of community wiki answer

Comment: @A.Wolff: I’m not sure what to do with this question, so it’s just an answer that I won’t get any reputation from, because people are annoyed with leaving answers in comments, but I’m annoyed with wrong answers, and askers are annoyed by closed questions.

Comment: That's ok, i'm giving then +1 to the *annoyed* community ;)